# when start application on cloudfoundry got error of 310, "web.xml not found"

Tags: cloud-foundry

Today when I tried to run the sample application hello-java which from git@github.com:SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples.git, I got the following errors when start the application,

Starting hello-java-from-linux-1... FAILED
CFoundry::AppStagingError: 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.64/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:28:in `block in stage_application': Web application staging failed: web.xml not found (RuntimeError)
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.64/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in`chdir'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.64/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in `stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in`'

I've checked the target war "hello-java-1.0.war" built by maven, the web.xml has been already packaged under WEB-INF.

Here is the pom.xml of the sample application,

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.cloudfoundry.samples
    hello-java
    1.0
    war
    
        
            javax.servlet
            servlet-api
            2.5
            provided

And here are the vmc version and maven version info, 
- vmc 0.4.7, 
- Apache Maven 3.0.4

Can anyone help on how to solve the issue? Thanks a lot!

BTW, I've searched the cloudfoundry support site, and found some tips to check log files, however seems that I cannot get log files to check the real error, I ran into the following issues when tried to get the log files.

[niy@niy-fedora hello-java]$ vmc files hello-java-from-linux-1 logs
Getting file contents... FAILED
CFoundry::AppStopped: 305: Operation not permitted on a stopped app
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

Comment: I just deployed the example to http://hello-java-gary.cloudfoundry.com from STS Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201210061308 and that worked, so let's go from there. I imported the example as a maven (embedded 3.0.4) project.

Comment: Thank you for answer, and I'll try from STS or eclipse, still just wonder why it cannot work with most suggested way of vmc.

Answer (score 3):

When deploying a java or spring WAR with vmc it's important to be in the same directory as the WAR file at the time you execute vmc.

Comment: I am using Cloud9 and AppFog to learn Java web development and I was blocked with this error. If you encounter this, just cd into the directory where your WAR is and do an update. Thanks @eightyoctane =).